# Multiple IF Statements in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to write multiple IF conditions in a sql statement.
I want to know that IF SMB is 1, then check if ACT, REN or REP is 1, select QF column from resp table and I want a single answer as 'a' and 'b' as its sum.

```
Input :

 @SMB = 1,@Dealer  = 0, @Act  = 1, @Ren = 1, @Rep = 1


tblACT:
QF
1
2

tblREP
QF
1
2

tblREN
QF
1
2


OUTPUT :
a b
6 0

@SMB bit = 1,
@Dealer bit = 1,
@Act bit = 1,
@Ren bit = 1,
@Rep bit = 1

Select SUM(tbl.a), SUM(tbl.b) from 
(If @SMB ='1'
    If @ACT ='1'  
       CASE WHEN QF IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as a 
       CASE WHEN QF IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as b from tblACT
    union all
    If @REN='1'  
      CASE WHEN QF IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as a
       CASE WHEN QF IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as b from tblREN
    union all
    If @REP='1'  
       CASE WHEN QF IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as a
       CASE WHEN QF IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as b from tblREP
union all
If @Dealer ='1'
   If @ACT ='1'  
       CASE WHEN QF IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as a
       CASE WHEN QF IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as b from tblACT
    union all
    If @REN='1'  
      CASE WHEN QF IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as a
       CASE WHEN QF IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as b from tblREN
    union all
    If @REP='1'  
       CASE WHEN QF IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as a
       CASE WHEN QF IN (4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 as b from tblREP) as tbl
```

Comment: What help do you need ? what output are you expecting?

Comment: This is not working. It gives syntax error and what not

Comment: provide you table structure and table data and output example

Comment: Can you share the syntax error and what not with us? Perhaps setup a SQL fiddle?

Comment: A more thorough explanation of what you're trying to do might help, as it's hard to tell what you're after from your attempted query.  Ideally you could add sample data and desired output.

Comment: I edited it. Kept desired output

Comment: Sorry, I have created my table and data with my understanding ... please test and let me  know if you need more help

Comment: Hey sorry, but i don't see any thing different in condition of SMB and Dealer... and please always write clear answer so it would be help you to get answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try This and let me know.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(   
    QF INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1) 
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2) 
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (5)


DECLARE @SMB bit ,@Dealer BIT,@Act bit ,@Ren BIT,@Rep bit 
SET @SMB = 1
SET @Dealer = 1
SET @Act = 1
SET @Ren = 1
SET @Rep = 1

SELECT  SUM(( CASE WHEN ( @SMB = 1
                          OR @Dealer = 1
                        )
                        AND @ACT = 1
                        AND QF IN ( 1, 2 ) THEN 1
                   WHEN ( @SMB = 1
                          OR @Dealer = 1
                        )
                        AND @REN = 1
                        AND QF IN ( 1, 2 ) THEN 1
                   WHEN ( @SMB = 1
                          OR @Dealer = 1
                        )
                        AND @REP = 1
                        AND QF IN ( 1, 2 ) THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
              END )) AS A ,
        SUM(( CASE WHEN ( @SMB = 1
                          OR @Dealer = 1
                        )
                        AND @ACT = 1
                        AND QF IN ( 4, 5 ) THEN 1
                   WHEN ( @SMB = 1
                          OR @Dealer = 1
                        )
                        AND @REN = 1
                        AND QF IN ( 4, 5 ) THEN 1
                   WHEN ( @SMB = 1
                          OR @Dealer = 1
                        )
                        AND @REP = 1
                        AND QF IN ( 4, 5 ) THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
              END )) AS B
FROM    #tmp
```

Comment: CASE WHEN ( @SMB = 1 OR Dealer = 1)
should not come, as tables are different for everything